# Matching a lower-case character on the position before an uppercase character (camelCase)?

Tags: regex, typescript

I have a regex in a piece of Typescript code that is used to match strings where there is a space, a dash/underscore or camelcase.

Because this pattern also is used to split the string later, in the case of the camelcase I actually need to match the lowercase character immediately before the camelcase/uppercase character, because I am trying to catch the camelcase. I am trying to reduce a string into two "initials" basically, so if I would input my alias for example "saddexProductions" or "Saddex Productions" etc, the output would be "SP". If there is no indicator that the string consists of two parts, for example "Saddexproductions", the output will be "Sa". If I match the uppercase character in the middle of the string though and split there, that character will be removed and the result with input "saddexProductions" would be "SR".

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
const splitRegex: RegExp = /\s|(?<=.)([a-z](?<=[A-Z]{1}))|\-|\_/;
```

Specifically, it is this part that is relevant:

```
(?<=.)([a-z](?<=[A-Z]{1}))
```

All the other scenarios I have described but this one give the desired result. There can be pretty much anything in front and following the camelcase, but it is always the single lowercase character before the uppercase character that needs to be matched, not the uppercase character.

How would I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your regex, `(?<=.)([a-z](?<=[A-Z]{1}))` does not seem to do anything meaningful as a char cannot match both `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` at the same time without the `i` modifier.

Comment: Well the thing is that I don't want to match the uppercase character itself, but only the lowercase character immediately before it, and not any lowercase characters - only if they are followed by an uppercase character.

Comment: Ok, try `const splitRegex: RegExp = /[-_\s]|([a-z](?=[A-Z]))/;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const splitRegex: RegExp = /[-_\s]|([a-z](?=[A-Z]))/;
```

*Details*:

- `[-_\s]` - a character class matching a `-`, `_` or a whitespace
- `|` - or
- `([a-z](?=[A-Z]))` - a capturing group with ID=1 that matches a lowercase ASCII letter followed with an uppercase ASCII letter without adding the latter to the overall match value (as it is inside a positive lookahead that is a non-consuming regex construct).